# addeventlistener to anchors to prompt an infowindow in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, loops, google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener

I am a begginner in javascript, and I know that my code is a little messy. I feel as though I may have stepped on my own foot here but I am really hoping that there is some sort of work around.

What I am wondering is what the best way to add the event listener to the anchors is. Right now, I have a loop that sets all the markers on the map (so I didn't have to write the  line of code each time for each marker) but looking back at it I am wondering if there is even a way to add an event listener now.

I have a list of links on the page, and I have an array full of data that i use to tag various things. What I need is to be able to click on the link (where it says "map it!") and for the info window to be prompted, and then I need to toggle that so that it closes if another one is opened

the website can be found here:
http://www.michiganwinetrail.com
And here is the full javascript page
http://www.michiganwinetrail.com/mainmap2.js

the code for the loop that I need to edit (which can be found at the bottom of that javascript link) is as follows:

```
function loadMap() {


var centerMich = new google.maps.LatLng(44.229457, -85.100098);
var myOptions = {
    center: centerMich,
    zoom: 7,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mainMichMap"), myOptions);

var homesouthwestDiv = document.createElement('div');
var homenorthwestDiv = document.createElement('div');
var homesoutheastDiv = document.createElement('div');
homesouthwestDiv.index = 1;
homenorthwestDiv.index = 2;
homesoutheastDiv.index = 3;
var homeControl = {
southwest: swRegions(homesouthwestDiv, map),
northwest: nwRegions(homenorthwestDiv, map),
southeast: seRegions(homesoutheastDiv, map),
};



map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(homesouthwestDiv);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(homenorthwestDiv);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(homesoutheastDiv);




for (var i=0; i<=locations.length; i++) {




        locations[i][0] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        title: locations[i][3],
        map: map,
        content:  locations[i][4]});

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
});

        google.maps.event.addListener(locations[i][0], 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.content);
        infowindow.open(map,this);
});


}


}
```

Answer (score -1):

On click of the link you need to do something like this:

```
var myHtml = "<h2 class=\"firstHeading\">" + winery.name + "</h2>";
map.openInfoWindowHtml(new GLatLng(winery.fltLat, winery.fltLng), myHtml);
```

I had done a similar demo some time ago: http://dipoletech.com/beermenu/